# javascript array index ascending by value value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I have an array which one including below values:

tomb = [4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2]

```
tomb[0] = 4
tomb[1] = 6
tomb[2] = 1
tomb[3] = 3
tomb[4] = 5
tomb[5] = 0
tomb[6] = 2
```

Can I ask is possible to convert like this:

```
tomb[5] = 0
tomb[2] = 1
tomb[6] = 2
tomb[3] = 3
tomb[0] = 4
tomb[4] = 5
tomb[1] = 6
```

I would like to use in for loop this array values, but before I have to start from the minimum and increase to the biggest one. So I would like get a array index list from minimum to maximum.

```
const arr = [4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2];
const min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
const index = arr.indexOf(min);
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one by using `array.sort` and `array.indexOf`

```js
const arr = [4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2];
const newarr = arr.slice()
const arrindex = []
newarr.sort()
newarr.forEach(i=>{
arrindex.push(arr.indexOf(i))
})
console.log(arrindex)
```

Comment: Thank you very much i tried and its worked very well! This is excatly what i tried to do. thank you

Comment: @zsolti900, glad I could help=)

Answer (score 3):

You could get the keys of the array and sort the indices by the values of the given array.

```js
const
    array = [4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2],
    indices = [...array.keys()].sort((a, b) => array[a] - array[b]);

console.log(...indices);
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of that  Good one!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
const arr = [4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2];
const sorted = arr
    .map((value, index) => ({ index, value }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
console.log(
    sorted.map(entry => entry.index),
    sorted.map(entry => entry.value)
)
```

Comment: I think OP wants to keep the order of the array, but sort indexes

Comment: Oh, right. I updated my answer